# Dar alert depois de digitada a palavra "passe"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu posso executar um alert apos o usuario escrever "stack".

Por exemplo,estou aqui postando isso e apos eu escrever `stack` (sem ser numa input, apenas escrevendo) ele dá um alert.

Teria que usar keypress e which ara checar as teclas que estao sendo digitadas, porem como poderei salvar cada letra ate a palavra bater?

Answer (score 9):

De forma simples, isso é o que você pode fazer:

```js
var memoria = "";
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    letra = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); // Capture a letra digitada
    memoria += letra;                       // Adicione no final da memória
    memoria = memoria.substr(-5);           // Mantenha apenas as 5 ultimas letras
    if (memoria == "STACK") {
        alert("Parabéns!")
    }
}
```

A cada tecla digitada, obtenha a letra correspondente e armazene em uma string. Quando o final dessa string for igual à palavra passe, faça algo.

Tome apenas o cuidado de ir limpando essa memória para que ela não cresça absurdamente. Nesse exemplo, é sempre mantido no máximo 5 caracteres, já que esse é o comprimento da palavra passe.

Comment: Você poderia colocar `memoria = '';` dentro do `if` assim o alert dispara toda vez que aparecer uma nova ocorrência da palavra

Comment: @renatoargh Não dispara, pois a próxima letra digitada vai mudar a memória.

Comment: Ah cara, agora entendi! +1

Answer (score 6):

Minha solução é semelhante à do Guilherme Bernal, porém limpa o buffer de teclas se você demorar demais entre uma letra e outra:

```js
var intervaloMaximo = 2000;
var timestamp = Date.now();
var palavra = "";

function tecla(e) {
    var agora = Date.now();
    if(agora - timestamp <= intervaloMaximo) {
         palavra += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    } else {
         palavra = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    }

    timestamp = agora;
    
    // Seu alert
    if(palavra === 'STACK') alert('stack!');
    
    // monitorando a palavra digitada
    // para fins demonstrativos
    document.getElementById('palavra').innerHTML = palavra;
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', tecla);
```

```html
<div id="palavra"></div>
```

Comment: Boa. Até em questão de usabilidade. O usuário tem memória de curto prazo, se ele digitar "CK" e de repente aparecer o alert ele não entenderá que a senha é STACK.

Comment: @bfavaretto Porque você e o @Guilherme Bernal optaram por `keyup` ao invés de `keypress` ou `keydown`?

Comment: @renatoargh No meu caso, por uma questão de hábito, e porque acho mais natural reagir ao que foi digitado só depois de tirar o dedo da tecla.

Comment: @renatoargh Dessa forma o alert não vai aparecer enquanto o usuário ainda está segurando a tecla. Pode ficar meio conflitante de outra forma.